# How to detect physical key click in a android wearable?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am using sony smartwatch 3 and it has a power button which I want to control or say manipulate.
I have already tried using :

```
onKeyDown()
onKeyUp()
onKeyLongPress()
```

but with no success it doesn't even detect the press of key.

I have also tried using `dispatchkeyevent(keyevent event)` and `shouldOverrideKeyEvent(keyevent event)`but again no success.
Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize and connect with GoogleApiClient. Once you clicks the button you have to get list of nodes and send a [message](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) to them. The last step is to read this message fron phone part of app, this can be done by registering proper WearableListenerService. Please see the sample code below.

**Wearable App:**

```
public class WearableButtonActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wearable_button_activity);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View target) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
            return;

        final PendingResult<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult> nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient);
        nodes.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result) {
                final List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if (nodes != null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++) {
                        final Node node = nodes.get(i);

                        // You can just send a message
                        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), "/MESSAGE", null);

                        // or you may want to also check check for a result:
                        // final PendingResult<SendMessageResult> pendingSendMessageResult = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), "/MESSAGE", null);
                        // pendingSendMessageResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                        //      public void onResult(SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                        //          if (sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode()==WearableStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                        //              // do something is successed
                        //          }
                        //      }
                        // });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Listener:**

```
 findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButtonClicked(v);
        }
    });
```

**Phone App:**

```
public class DataLayerListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        if("/MESSAGE".equals(messageEvent.getPath())) {
            // launch some Activity or do anything you like
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my question was how to detect press of physical key i.e. hardware key such as power button not a XML button which u told.So i cannot accept this answer.If u have any suggestions regarding hardware key then please guide me @d.datul1990